# Lynx Cookies with Cloudflare Denied

Tags: cookies, cloudflare, lynx

When using Lynx on a Cloudflare website  I received this error.

> Please enable cookies.

> Sorry, you have been blocked

then I edit the settings in Lynx under 'security and privacy' I make 'Cookies (!) [accept all]' save then still received the same error.

does anyone have a simple work around for this?
here is the link that I can't get to work in Lynx.

`https://hiphoplossless.com/`

Comment: It's triggered by the user-agent.  "Web developers" (as opposed to software developers) do this a lot.  To work around, in Lynx's options menu, uncheck the ["Send User-Agent header"](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html#optinfo-send_user_agent).